# Swatting police/fire from someone else's cellphone... possible?

Tags: cellular

Scenario- calls for 911 service are being made from the cell phone belonging to a young adult. These calls show as outgoing calls on the cell call log (and texts). These have been occurring for over a year and each time appear to be from the child's phone. When traced by the dispatch center, the call shows to be coming from the address of the child (physical location of the cell phone).

The father of the child claims that a disgruntled family member has technology that allows them to make these malicious calls from their location in another state, making it appear that the child is making the calls.

Further, the voice of the person making the calls resembles the child during playback, but voice analyzation is not an option due to the quality of the recording (so I was told).

Is this technology possible? All of the evidence is pointing toward the young adult making the false calls. Looking for any help with this unique situation.

Thanks in advance.